# File download via PHP being mysteriously interrupted on Dreamhost

Tags: php, file, http, connection, dreamhost

I've written a simple PHP script to download a hidden file if the user has proper authentication. The whole set up works fine: it sends the proper headers, and the file transfer begins just fine (and ends just fine - for small files).

However, when I try to serve a 150 MB file, the connection gets mysteriously interrupted somewhere close to the middle of the file. Here's the relevant code fragment (taken from somewhere on the Internet and adapted by me):

```
    function readfile_chunked($filename, $retbytes = TRUE) {
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    if ($handle === false) return false;
    while (!feof($handle) and (connection_status()==0)) {
        print(fread($handle, 1024*1024));
        set_time_limit(0);
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
    return fclose($handle);
}
```

I also do some other code BEFORE calling that function above, to try to solve the issue, but as far as I can tell, it does nothing:

```
    session_write_close();
    ob_end_clean();

    ignore_user_abort();
    set_time_limit(0);
```

As you can see, it doesn't attempt to load the whole file in memory at once or anything insane like that. To make it even more puzzling, the actual point in the transfer where it kills it seems to float between 50 and 110 MB, and it seems to kill ALL connections to the same file within a few seconds of each other (tried this by trying to download simultaneously with a friend). Nothing is appended to the interrupted file, and I see no errors on the logs.

I'm using Dreamhost, so I suspect that their watchdog might be killing my process because it's been running for too long. Does anyone have any experience to share on the matter? Could something else be the issue? Is there any workaround?

For the record, my Dreamhost is setup to use PHP 5.2.1 FastCGI.

Comment: interesting. Maybe you should log the output to a file with some stats like running processes and memory usage. might be useful.

Comment: I would suspect that it is either killing your process because it is long running, or more likely, that is is killing it because you are consuming too much memory.

Answer (score 1):

I have little experience with Dreamhost, but you could use [mod_xsendilfe](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) instead (if Dreamhost allows it).